# programmatically check if coupon code is correct

Tags: controllers, ajax, coupon

I need  to check to see if a coupon code is correct in an ajax controller, how is this done?

I get the code like this:

$param['code'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
couponCode = $param['code'] 
$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($couponCode, 'code');
$oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());
```

Then try to apply it to your order see [Check if coupon is valid for a quote](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4922/check-if-coupon-is-valid-for-a-quote)

Comment: try to apply oRule with setCouponCode?

Comment: Suppose a coupon os valid until yesterday and I would execute this code. Would it then return an error or empty?